# How do I apply Drag-and-Drop to both move objects and transfer data?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF desktop app, I have numerous instances of a UserControl which appear on a grid. I want the ability to drag any control around on the screen and, if I drop it onto another control beneath, have a data transfer occur from the dragged object to the drop target. Seems like it should be simple, but I'm having a very hard time getting WPF to do both things at the same time.

In [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-enabling-drag-and-drop-on-a-user-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for enabling Drag-and-Drop (DND) on a User Control,
the code initiating the DND is within the  objects themselves, and the data transfer works, but the objects never move on the screen.
In this [other DND example](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/main/Drag%20and%20Drop/DragDropObjects/MainWindow.cs) which includes moving objects around on the screen,
the DND code which moves the objects all happens in the window. Everything can be dragged around quite nicely, but there's no data transfer between the dragged objects. 
Is anyone aware of a single example that manages both objectives--dragging a UserControl (or an Adorner) around on the screen and doing data transfer from the dragged object to another object underneath?

Answer (score 0):

In the second example that uses an adorner to visually indicate that the object is being dragged, you can create a `DataObject` yourself in the `DragStarted()` method, store it somewhere (like for example in a class variable) and then retrieve it from this storage in the `DragFinished` method, e.g.:

```
private DataObject data;

private void DragStarted()
{
    _isDragging = true;
    _originalLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(_originalElement);
    _originalTop = Canvas.GetTop(_originalElement);

    data = new DataObject();
    data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, "some data...");
    data.SetData("Object", _originalElement);

    _overlayElement = new SimpleCircleAdorner(_originalElement);
    var layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(_originalElement);
    layer.Add(_overlayElement);
}

private void DragFinished(bool cancelled)
{
    Mouse.Capture(null);
    if (_isDragging)
    {
        AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(_overlayElement.AdornedElement).Remove(_overlayElement);

        if (cancelled == false)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(_originalElement, _originalTop + _overlayElement.TopOffset);
            Canvas.SetLeft(_originalElement, _originalLeft + _overlayElement.LeftOffset);
        }
        _overlayElement = null;

        string dataString = (string)data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);
        var obj = data.GetData("Object");
    }
    _isDragging = false;
    _isDown = false;
}
```

The difference is that you don't call `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` and don't handle the `Drop` event and to the data from the `DragEventArgs`. The data itself may be exactly the same but you store it in another location basically.